# JQuery - Prevent Page Refresh on From Submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm attempting to call a Asp.Net MVC endpoint via Ajax but I'm having trouble preventing the page from refreshing when I submit the form.

The from lives inside a Bootstrap model on a MVC ASP.Net View.

Here is the form (form.cshtml) ...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editPropertiesForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="modal fade" id="editPropertiesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Properties</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body form-group">

                    <div class="container">

                        <span id="responseMessage"></span>

                        <fieldset class="border pl-1 pr-4 mb-2">
                            <legend>Core Properties</legend>

                            @*Folder*@
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="formFolderPicker" class="col-sm-3">Folder(s)</label>
                                <select id="formFolderPicker" class="selectpicker form-control col-sm-9" multiple data-live-search="true" name="folders">
                                    @*Options bound via editPropertiesFormBuilder.js*@
                                </select>
                            </div>                       
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset class="border pl-1 pr-4 mb-2">
                            <legend>Other</legend>

                            @*Notes*@
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="formNotes" class="col-sm-3">Notes</label>
                                <textarea type="text" class="form-control col-sm-9" id="formNotes" name="notes" rows="3"></textarea>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="editPropertiesCloseBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        @*<button id="editPropertiesSaveBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>*@
                        <input id="editPropertiesSaveBtn" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the Jquery method that will eventually use Ajax and call a MVC endpoint ...

```
    $("#editPropertiesForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I'd expect the `event.preventDefault()` to work and prevent the page from reloading on submitting the form, but it isn't. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's possible the form is dynamically created if it's in the modal. Try using `$(document).on('submit', '#editPropertiesForm', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: btw I don't see `editPropertiesForm` button in your code. am I missing anything here?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: In that case check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no errors. I can put a console.log in there, will print the CL and then redirect.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I have a editPropertiesSaveBtn button the form. editPropertiesForm is the id of the form.

Comment: @Manjuboyz Why remove your answer and down vote?

Comment: @japesSophey I have not downvoted your answer, I can upvote if you need. I removed my answer because someone downvoted mine, so there is no need for an answer to sit incase if it downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the input type to button

```
<input id="editPropertiesSaveBtn" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

and in click event submit the form

```
$("#editPropertiesSaveBtn").on("click", function (e) {
     $("#editPropertiesForm").submit();
     e.preventDefault();
 })
```

Comment: This did the job, thank you. Because I use JQuery validation on the form, I had to do a extra check on the click to ensure the form was valid.